# WaitForSingleObject times out too fast

Tags: c++, winapi

I have this piece of code in a secondary thread:

```
DWORD result = WaitForSingleObject(myhandle,10000);
if(result == WAIT_OBJECT_0){
    AfxMessageBox(_T(...));
}
else if(result  == WAIT_TIMEOUT){

    AfxMessageBox(_T("Timeout"));
}
```

Sometimes, not always, the timeout will get called almost as soon as the WaitForSingleObject is called (not even 1s delay).

Am I doing something wrong ? Any suggestions for more stable alternatives ?

---

EDIT:

`myhandle` is created inside a class constructor as:

```
myhandle = CreateEvent(NULL,FALSE,FALSE,_T("myhandle"));
```

it would get called by another function:

```
SetEvent(myhandle);
```

The point is it works when I do the SetEvent, the problem is that it sometimes times out as soon as the WaitForSingleObject is called, even though it should wait 10s.

Comment: What are you waiting on? Where does myhandle come from?

Comment: Did you check `GetLastError()` before and after the wait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took awhile but the problem actually was that the program sometimes did multiple calls to `WaitForSingleObject`. So it's a previous call that is timing out.

Solution is to use `WaitForMultipleObjects` and set a cancelling event in the case it is known that the first event won't be set, so the timer is cancelled before is it re-invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need/want a named event? Typically this is only required for inter-process concurrency control.

If you have multiple instances of this class they will all use the same event - see the [docs for CreateEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about calling for a named object that already exists.

It may be that all you need to do is remove the name here.  This allows each class instance to have its own `Event` object and behaviour should be more predictable.

Comment: The class in which the event is created in is a singleton. It is set from the main view: `Class::instance()->SetEvent()` in which the piece of code is `SetEvent(myhandle);` I will try what you are suggesting i.e. CreateEvent(NULL,FALSE,FALSE,NULL)

Comment: Yes, but that only matters if multiple call that code.  Do you run more than one instance of the program?

Answer (score 1):

`WaitForSingleObject` will not wait the whole 10 seconds. It will wait for the first of:

1. The timeout value is elapsed
2. The event is signaled
3. The handle becomes invalid (closed in another thread)

If the event is set when you call `WaitForSingleObject`, condition #2 is true from the start and `WaitForSingleObject` returns immediatly.

If you want to *always* wait 10 seconds, you should use code like this :

```
//Always wait 10 seconds
Sleep(10000); 

//Test the event without waiting
if(WaitForSingleObject(myhandle, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Event was set in the last 10 secondes"));
} else {
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Timeout"));
}
```